# prove that a system $AX=Y$ has soloutions iff the row rank of A is same as that of the augmented matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a m by n matrix over the field F , I want to prove that a system $AX=Y$ has solutions iff the row rank of A is same as that of the augmented matrix of the system

My try:

I was thinking that in order to make the row rank equal the row space should be equal and to do that number of rows should be equal. Now since the number of rows of the augmented matrix is same as that of the matrix $A$ then the row space will be equal which will lead to the row rank being equal.

Is this idea right?

Comment: What are $A$, $X$ and $Y$? Where is the augmented matrix and how is it defined?

Comment: @mvw i have edited the question and only this much is given in the question

Comment: Upper case letters are usually used for matrices. The lacking information points to vectors.

Comment: @mvw thats how Hoffman Kunze mentions it

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Your argument claims that augmenting $A$ by **any** column vector $\vec y$ will never change the row rank. You haven't used the fact that $A\vec x = \vec y$ has a solution.

---

Let $[B \mid \vec z]$ be the row-reduced echelon form of $[A \mid \vec y]$. Recall that $A \vec x = \vec y$ has a solution iff:
$$\text{
$[B \mid \vec z]$
has no row of the form $[0 ~ 0 ~ \cdots ~ 0 \mid k]$ for some $k \neq 0$
} \tag{$\star$}$$
But since the row rank of $[A \mid \vec y]$ is precisely the number of nonzero rows in $[B \mid \vec z]$ and since the row rank of $A$ is precisely the number of nonzero rows in $B$, it follows that $(\star)$ occurs iff the row rank of $A$ equals the row rank of $[A \mid \vec y]$.

Comment: shouldnt it be that the if it is of that form which you wrote it would be inconsistent and have no soloutions@Adriano

Comment: Yes. That's why it says "...has **no** row of the form...".

Comment: oh sorry i didnt read that thanks for the answer